# Assigning dates to samples in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Given some arbitrary numpy array of data, how can I plot it to make dates appear on the x axis? In this case, sample 0 will be some time, say 7:00, and every sample afterwards will be spaced one minute apart, so that for 60 samples, the time displayed should be 7:00, 7:01, ..., 7:59.

I looked at some of the other questions on here but they all required actually setting a date and some other stuff that felt very over the top compared to what I'd like to do.

Thanks!

Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an array of datetime objects for your x-axis, the plot() function will behave like you want (assuming that you don't want all 60 labels from 7:00 to 7:59 to be displayed). Here is a sample code:

```
import random
from pylab import *
from datetime import *
N = 60
t0 = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(7,0,0))
delta_t = timedelta(minutes=1)
x_axis = t0 + arange(N)*delta_t
plot(x_axis, random(N))
show()
```

Concerning the use of the combine() function, see question [python time + timedelta equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656297/python-time-timedelta-equivalent)