# How to add hours and minutes between them

Tags: python-3.x

I want to do something like `2h35 + 0h56` in python. So this is what I tried :

```
>>> t1 = time(2, 35)
>>> t2 = time(0, 56)
>>> t3 = t1 + t2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

How can I add times on a time in Python ? All the subjects on Stackoverflow ask for add times on a date, but I just need time no date!

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is `time(14, 0) + time(14, 0)` supposed to yield (or any other times that add up to more than one day?

Comment: Easy, `28h`! It can be more than one day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t1 = datetime(year=2015, day=19, month=9, hour=2, minute=35)
    t2 = t1 + relativedelta(minutes=56)

    print(t2.strftime('%H:%m'))
```

You must specify a real date, but in your case, you are only interested in the hours and minutes, so you can just print them using strftime.

Comment: python-dateutil is really useful

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.time` represents absolute times and it doesn't make any sense to add e.g. `2:35 + 0:56`.

See [python time + timedelta equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656297/python-time-timedelta-equivalent). The solution there might help you.