# Pandas time series index based on datetime.time

Tags: python, pandas

I have time series with time stamps corresponding to timedeltas, but the actual time and date do not play a role. So I can assume some reference time point as a start for the time series.

```
ts = ref_time + pd.to_timedelta(dat["MILLISEC"], unit="ms")

dat.set_index(ts)
```

But I wonder if `ref_time` really needs to be of type `datetime.datetime` as I would prefer it to be of type `datetime.time`. But than I cannot use it as an index for Pandas as it seems. Why is that?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

I think yes, because `datetime.time` as python object is not implicitly converted to `timestamp` like `datetime.datetime`:

```
a = datetime.time(4) + pd.to_timedelta(['10:00:10','00:00:10'])
print (a)
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'TimedeltaIndex'

```
a = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1,4) + pd.to_timedelta(['10:00:10','00:00:10'])
print (a)

DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01 14:00:10', '2017-01-01 04:00:10'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Or create [`TimedeltaIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#timedeltaindex):

```
a = pd.Timedelta(4, unit='h') + pd.to_timedelta(['10:00:10','00:00:10'])
print (a)

TimedeltaIndex(['14:00:10', '04:00:10'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

EDIT:

It is not supported in pure python also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/656297/2901002).