# Python create time object and add some time (minutes) to it

Tags: python, python-3.x

**What I want:**

I have string, like that: `'1:48'` I want to add some minutes to it, for example 15 minutes and to print `'2:03'`.

**What is the problem:**

I am newbie to Python and following official documentation, I cannot do it.

**What I tried:**

After google research I found a way to create time object from string, like this:

```
import time
hours = input()
minutes = input()
time_str = hours + ':' + minutes;

test = time.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M')

print(test)
```

But I cannot find a method from `time` library which add time. I found that method in `datetime` (timedelta) library, but there is not a method which create time object from string.

Comment: _"but there is not a method which create time object from string."_ I don't understand. There _is_ a method, and you're using it: `time.strptime`.

Comment: Is this a *time of day*, i.e. "1:48am", or is this a *duration*, i.e. 108 minutes?

Comment: @Kevin Cannot find hat method in `datetime` library.

Comment: Of course, you have *no need* for such a method, as you're already asking for hours and minutes separately; why not pass them separately to `time()`?

Comment: @deceze It's 1:48am

Comment: If you're saying "there is not a method which creates a `datetime` method from string, that also exists: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime. If you're saying "there is not a method which creates a timedelta object from string", why would you need that? What's wrong with creating it like `x = datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)`?

Comment: Then you *should* associate it with a concrete date too. If you add a duration to a time of day, depending on local DST/timezone conditions, the answer may be very different depending on the day/the timezone. And if you do that, it's easy with a `datetime` object and a `timedelta` object.

Comment: @Kevin `Cannot find reference 'strptime' in 'datetime.pyi`

Comment: If you're saying "although time.strptime exists, this returns a `struct_time` object. I want an equivalent method that returns a datetime.time object. But there is no `datetime.time.strptime` method", then you could parse the string to datetime, then convert to time: `datetime.datetime.strptime("5:15", "%H:%M").time()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import datetime

t = "22:00"
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M')
(d + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime("%H:%M")
```

Comment: Why import time, and why import timedelta as well as datetime?

Comment: It's work, can I print without leading zero of hours ? `7:45` instead of `07:45` ?

Comment: Removed the time and timedelta import and made it shorter :)

Comment: Use "%-H:%M" if you want to remove the leading 0

Answer (score 4):

You can create `time` objects from string of type 'hh:mm:ss' by using some string operations like:

```
str=input('Enter time string: ')
h,m,s=str.split(':')
```

The pass it to time object:

```
import datetime
t=datetime.time(hour=h,minute=m,second=s)
```

Then you can use timedelta method to add/subtract time:

```
td=datetime.timedelta(hour=hd,minute=MD,second=sd)
tf=t+td
```

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'`, at least in Python 3. You need to use `combine`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/656394/1450294