# How to create a DateTime equal to 15 minutes ago?

Tags: python, datetime

I need to create a DateTime object that represents the current time minus 15 minutes.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/python-easy-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-a-datetime-time/100345#100345

Answer (score 288, accepted):

import datetime and then the magic timedelta stuff:

```
In [63]: datetime.datetime.now()
Out[63]: datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 27, 14, 39, 19, 700401)

In [64]: datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
Out[64]: datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 27, 14, 24, 21, 684435)
```

Comment: NB, in Python 3 you'll need to pass the timezone to `now()` to avoid an error about subtracting offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes: `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)`

Comment: @nornagon that’s not at all applicable here; it doesn’t matter if the datetime object is aware or naive, subtracting a timedelta works regardless.

Answer (score 42):

```
 datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
```

Answer (score 14):

This is simply what to do:

```py
datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes = 15)
```

[`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)s are specifically designed to allow you to subtract or add deltas (differences) to [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)s.

Answer (score 11):

```
import datetime 
datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(0, 900)

Actually 900 is in seconds. Which is equal to 15 minutes. `15*60 = 900`
```

Comment: Your import doesn’t match the code; you import `timedelta` but then use `datetime` attributes. Either import the module, or add the type.

Answer (score 9):

I have provide two methods for doing so for minutes as well as for years and hours if you want to see more examples:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now())
print(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes = 15))
print(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes = -15))
print(datetime.timedelta(hours = 5))
print(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = 3))
print(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = -9))
print(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 9))
```

I get the following results:

```
2016-06-03 16:04:03.706615
2016-06-03 15:49:03.706622
2016-06-03 15:49:03.706642
5:00:00
2016-06-06 16:04:03.706665
2016-05-25 16:04:03.706676
2016-05-25 16:04:03.706687
2016-06-03
16:04:03.706716
```

Answer (score 7):

Use DateTime in addition to a `timedelta` object
http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

`datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)`

Answer (score 7):

only the below code in Python 3.7 worked for me

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta    
print(datetime.now()-timedelta(seconds=900))
```

Comment: This is no different from much older answers here.

Comment: yes it is different. datetime.timedelta(..) does not work

Answer (score 4):

`datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(0, 15 * 60)`

`timedelta` is a "change in time". It takes days as the first parameter and seconds in the second parameter. `15 * 60` seconds is 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `time.time()` and wants timestamp as output

Simply use

```
CONSTANT_SECONDS = 900 # time  in seconds (900 seconds = 15 min)

current_time = int(time.time())
time_before_15_min = current_time - CONSTANT_SECONDS
```

You can change 900 seconds as per your required time.