# In Python, how do I make a datetime that is 15 minutes from now? 1 hour from now?

Tags: python, datetime

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Python - easy way to add N seconds to a datetime.time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/python-easy-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-a-datetime-time)
>   [How to create a DateTime equal to 15 minutes ago?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541629/how-to-create-a-datetime-equal-to-15-minutes-ago)

what's the best way to do this?

Comment: This has already been answered lots of times, please search for it. The exact question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541629/how-to-create-a-datetime-equal-to-15-minutes-ago.  Let's think.  That answer must be helpful.  And -- bonus -- it contains some links to other duplicate questions.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
d1 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
d2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```