# How to convert orderdict into json in python?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-serializer

How to convert below orderedict into regular json ? in python?

> [OrderedDict([('ins_short_name', 'MI'), ('beneficiary', []),
>   ('benefit', 65), ('pcp', []), ('benefit_rates', 216),
>   ('added_dependent', []), ('removed_dependent', []), ('ins_name',
>   'Medical Insurance'), ('plan', {'carrier_logo':
>   '[How to create a DateTime equal to 15 minutes ago?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541629/how-to-create-a-datetime-equal-to-15-minutes-ago)',
>   'plan_type': 'HMO', 'creation_time': '2019-02-11T06:21:21.743369Z',
>   'plan_info_details': '', 'rx_coverage': '11', 'id': 65, 'co_pay':
>   '11', 'contribution_interval': None, 'updation_time':
>   '2019-02-11T06:21:21.743808Z', 'benefit_display_name': 'Mi1 HMO',
>   'carrier': 1, 'status': False, 'carrier_name': 'NHP',
>   'rx_information': None, 'voluntary': False, 'deductible': '11`',
>   'hsa_qualified_wrap_plan': False, 'benefit': 65,
>   'terms_and_conditions': None, 'maximum_contribution': None,
>   'hsa_qualified_base_plan': False, 'primary_care_physician': False,
>   'plan_info': ''}), ('dependent', []), ('questions',
>   [OrderedDict([('question', 1), ('question_type', 'radio'),
>   ('identifier', 'Q1'), ('ref', [Decimal('1.00')])]),
>   OrderedDict([('question', 4), ('question_type', 'plan'),
>   ('identifier', 'Q4'), ('ref', [Decimal('216.00')])])])]),
>   OrderedDict([('ins_short_name', 'AI'), ('beneficiary',
>   [OrderedDict([('id', 365), ('first_name', 'rer'), ('last_name',
>   'ere'), ('relation', 'Spouse'), ('other_relation', None), ('_type',
>   'Primary'), ('percentage', '100'), ('benefit', 66), ('enrollment',
>   357), ('creation_time', '2019-02-14T12:04:00.676078Z'),
>   ('updation_time', '2019-02-14T12:04:33.475164Z')])]), ('benefit', 66),
>   ('pcp', []), ('benefit_rates', None), ('added_dependent', []),
>   ('removed_dependent', []), ('ins_name', 'Ancillary Insurance'),
>   ('plan', {'carrier_logo':
>   '[How to create a DateTime equal to 15 minutes ago?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541629/how-to-create-a-datetime-equal-to-15-minutes-ago)',
>   'plan_type': 'Other', 'creation_time': '2019-02-11T06:24:32.322178Z',
>   'plan_info_details': '', 'rx_coverage': '', 'id': 66, 'co_pay': '',
>   'contribution_interval': None, 'updation_time':
>   '2019-02-11T06:24:32.322541Z', 'benefit_display_name': 'Ai name',
>   'carrier': 1, 'status': False, 'carrier_name': 'NHP',
>   'rx_information': None, 'voluntary': True, 'deductible': '',
>   'hsa_qualified_wrap_plan': False, 'benefit': 66,
>   'terms_and_conditions': None, 'maximum_contribution': None,
>   'hsa_qualified_base_plan': False, 'primary_care_physician': False,
>   'plan_info': ''}), ('dependent', []), ('questions',
>   [OrderedDict([('question', 12), ('question_type', 'radio'),
>   ('identifier', 'Q12'), ('ref', [Decimal('10.00')])])])])]

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? I mean, really, what have you tried AT ALL ? (hint: did you _at least_ triythe very very very much obvious `json.dumps()` ?)

Comment: The problem here won't e the OrderedDict, but the fact that it contains Decimals.

Comment: yes @DanielRoseman thats the problem. Thank you so much fo your comment and I have tried with another way and got the answer.