# How to use striptime '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' minus - 1 minute.?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to basically use striptime that gives me format of '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' etc `'2019-05-03 09:00:00'` and what I am trying to achieve is that I want to take that time - 1 minute so the output should be - `2019-05-03 08:59:00`

what I have done so far is

```
    date_time = '2019-05-03 09:00:00'
    target = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    now = datetime.now()

    delta = target - now

    if delta > timedelta(0):
        print('Will sleep {} : {}'.format(date_time, delta))
        time.sleep(delta.total_seconds())
```

and I am not sure how I can make the function to do - 1 minute. I am not sure if its even possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541629/how-to-create-a-datetime-equal-to-15-minutes-ago

Comment: @Meow When I try to do `target(minutes=-1)` i will get an error saying `TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you meant to use the formatted datetime variable called `target` in your if clause but instead you used the string representation of that date called `date_time`.

Use the datetime object instead and substract `timedelta(minutes=1)`

Working example:

```
date_time = '2019-05-03 09:00:00'
target = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

now = datetime.now()

delta = target - now

if delta > timedelta(0):
    target = target - timedelta(minutes=1)
    print('Will sleep {} : {}'.format(target, delta))
    time.sleep(delta.total_seconds())
```

Comment: I would believe you need to move `target = target - timedelta(minutes=1)` up to between `now = datetime.now` and `delta = target - now` to actually make it start 1 min before the real target time?

Comment: Yes, if you want to subtract the minute before the if statement evaluation you should definitely do that.

Comment: Thank you! It was exactly what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the current time to determine your output

```
import datetime, time
from datetime import timedelta

daytime = '2019-05-03 09:00:00'
target = datetime.datetime.strptime(daytime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print (datetime.datetime.now())

now = datetime.datetime.now()
new_time = target-now

if  new_time > datetime.timedelta(0):
        print('Will sleep {} : {}'.format(daytime, new_time))
        time.sleep(new_time.total_seconds())
```