# Pythonic way to combine datetime.date and datetime.time objects

Tags: datetime, python

I have two objects that represent the same event instance --- one holds the date, the other the time of this event, and I want to create a datetime object.

Since one can't simply add date and time objects (following call fails):

```
 datetime.date(2011, 01, 01) + datetime.time(10, 23)
```

Comment: See [What is the standard way to add N seconds to datetime.time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100210/562769)

Answer (score 478, accepted):

It's in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine).

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(2011, 1, 1), 
                          datetime.time(10, 23))
```

returns

```
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 10, 23)
```

Comment: This loses the tzinfo though (if the date has one). Is there a way to keep it?

Comment: And in Python 3? Can't find `combine()`

Comment: @OlivierPons nothing has changed in Python3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine

Comment: I'm sorry you're right, `combine()` can be applied to a `datetime` value. Thanks a lot

Comment: add timezone info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065242/2544138

Comment: In Python 3.6, you can use the `tzinfo` argument to preserve timezone: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine