# Python - merge time and date

Tags: python, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pythonic way to add datetime.date and datetime.time objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474670/pythonic-way-to-add-datetime-date-and-datetime-time-objects)

This question seems quite simple for me but I can't find the answer.
I have a `datetime.date()` to which I'd like to add a `datetime.time()`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> my_time = datetime.time(9, 30)
>>> my_date = datetime.date(2012, 10, 2)
```

I tried

```
>>> my_time + my_date
```

I would have liked to get a

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 2, 9, 30)
```

But the operand is not supported.
What is the best way to add `my_time` to `my_date` ?

Comment: It's indeed a duplicate. I was not finding because I didn't use the good keywords

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(2011, 01, 01), datetime.time(10, 23))`

http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine

Comment: This seemed simple and is in fact simple :) Thanks