# add datetime with datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474670/pythonic-way-to-add-datetime-date-and-datetime-time-objects) but with an important difference.

I have two datetime objects like

```
In [87]: d
Out[87]: datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 0)
In [88]: m
Out[88]: datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 6, 0)
```

I want to add the time part of d to m to get

```
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 0)
```

The other question gives me datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 0) when i combine m and d.time() as

```
In [90]: print datetime.datetime.combine(m, d.time())
1900-01-01 02:00:00
```

I know that the other way of doing this would be to use timedelta as

```
In [91]: print m + datetime.timedelta(hours=d.hour, minutes=d.minute)
1900-01-01 08:00:00
```

But, is there a more pythonic way?

Comment: so you want to sum *just* the time portions of the dates, regardless of the date portion? Then your only option is the one you already found.

Comment: seems pretty pythonic to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
In [1]: import datetime as DT

In [2]: d = DT.datetime(1900,1,1,2,0)

In [3]: m = DT.datetime(1900,1,1,6,0)

In [4]: delta = d - DT.datetime(1900,1,1,0,0)

In [5]: m + delta
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 0)
```

But note that this will give you a different answer if the year/month/date of `d` are different than 1900/1/1.

Comment: You could use `d - DT.datetime.combine(d.date(), DT.time.min)` to create a delta. Or just `DT.timedelta(hours=d.hour, minutes=d.minute, seconds=d.second)`, but the OP already figured that much out.

Comment: Yup, To clarify, I actually just need to add two times but I guess thats not there so I'm loading them into datetime objects using strptime. So, the date being different wont be a problem here I think. Thanks!