# Adding <type 'datetime.date'> and <type 'datetime.time'>

Tags: python

I have 2017-07-21 as a'datetime.date'  object and

15:30:00 as a datetime.time' object

How do I combine the two to get

2017-07-21-15:30:00?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to add datetime.date and datetime.time objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474670/pythonic-way-to-add-datetime-date-and-datetime-time-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datetime.combine` from `datetime`.

```
import datetime

d = datetime.date(2017, 07, 21)
t = datetime.time(15, 30, 0)
dt = datetime.datetime.combine(d, t)
```

Answer (score 2):

> *classmethod* `datetime.combine(`*date*, *time*, *tzinfo*=*self.tzinfo*)
>
> Return a new `datetime` object whose date components are equal to the given `date` object’s, and whose time components are equal to the given `time` object’s.

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine)

Answer (score 0):

```
     >>> from datetime import datetime, date, time

        >>> d = date(2017, 7, 21)
        >>> t = time(15, 30, 0)
        >>> newDate = datetime.combine(d, t)
        >>> newDate
        datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 21, 15, 30)
        >>> newDate.strftime(%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S)
        '2017-07-21-15:30:00'
```

You can use the `datetime.combine` method as above. More about info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time)