# Add time in Present date using Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I want to add particular time in present date.
e.g. **2020-10-22 12:00:00**.
For that I have tried in the following way

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
duration = "12:00:00"
duration_obj = datetime.strptime(duration, '%H:%M:%S')
Date_Time = date.today() + duration_obj
```

But , I'm gettimg an error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Any suggestion will be helpful....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to construct a timedelta object from a simple string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string)

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474670/pythonic-way-to-add-datetime-date-and-datetime-time-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `12:00:00` to `datetime.time` object using `fromisoformat`, convert that to seconds and add it to the actual time:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time
duration = "12:00:00"
duration_obj = time.fromisoformat(duration)
total_seconds = duration_obj.second + duration_obj.minute*60 + duration_obj.hour*3600

Date_Time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=total_seconds)
print(datetime.now())
print(Date_Time)
```

Out:

```
2020-10-22 17:30:15.878372
2020-10-23 05:30:15.878357
```

**Edit** (using datetime.combine):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time
duration = "12:00:00"
duration_obj = time(*(int(x) for x in duration.split(':')))
Date_Time = datetime.combine(date.today(), duration_obj)
print(Date_Time)
>>>2020-10-22 12:00:00
```

**Construct the datetime object directly:**

```
duration = "12:00:00"
_today = date.today()

datetimeList = [_today.year, _today.month, _today.day] + [int(x) for x in duration.split(':')]
Date_Time = datetime(*datetimeList)
print(Date_Time)
>>> 2020-10-22 12:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I need to add particular time in present date ...not in time. kindly see e.g. once

Comment: @Addy: Got it. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Transform them into `string` before concatenation:

```
separator = " | " 
date_time = str(date.today()) + separator + duration
```

The error is telling you that those operands: `datetime.date` and `datetime.datetime` object are not valid for `+` concatenation operation.

Comment: you should at least add a separator between the strings ;-) ...and it should be mentioned that this returns a string whilst the OP's code suggests he wants a datetime object.

Comment: It worked, but some default date come in output **2020-10-221900-01-01 12:00:00**

Comment: Okei sorry, i don't get well why you want to transform `12:00:00` into a `datetime` and then convert it back to `string` ? May you do as i did above ?

Comment: I got answer..but is it in datetime format??if no then how to convert this str into datetime