# Convert datetime.time in datetime.datetime

Tags: python, datetime, time

i want to calculate difference in seconds, between two dates.

```
def delta_seconds(datetime, origin):
   td = datetime - origin  # datetime - date
   return float((td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10 ** 6)) / 10 ** 6
```

I can't compute the difference and it shows me this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.datetime
```

So, i want to convert datetime.time into datetime.datetime.

(datetime is a datetime.time obj and origin is a datetime.datetime obj)

Any suggestion?

Comment: your question says "difference between dates" but you use datetime.time? can you give a concrete example?

Comment: I retrive a timestamp from an nmea sentence (object_nmea.timestamp). This timestamp is datetime.time obj. 
Then I retrive date from a nmea sentence (object_nmea.date), and it is a datetime.date obj. I convert it into datetime.datetime. 
Now, with theese, i want to calcultate the difference in seconds

Comment: ok to get that right, you have a date and a time, which you *combine* to a datetime object? and you want to know how many seconds have passed on that date (given a certain time)?

Comment: Yes, i've two dates, and i want to know how many seconds have passed from datetime (datetime.time) and origin (datetime.datetime). But i can't do that because they have not the same type

Comment: you can easily get a datetime object from a date object by combining it with time zero; like `datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.combine(date_obj, datetime.time(0))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Never perform calculations yourself when you can get the desired things from the standard library. The difference between two `datetime.datetime` objects gives you `datetime.timedelta` which already has a class attribute, `seconds` which you can return from your function.
2. You can use [`datetime.combine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to combine `datetime.date` and `datetime.time`.

**Demo:**

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time


def delta_seconds(end, origin):
    return (end - origin).seconds


# Test
date = date(2021, 5, 3)
time = time(10, 20, 30)
origin = datetime.combine(date, time)
end = datetime.now()
print(delta_seconds(end, origin))
```

**Output:**

```
33213
```

Comment: Ah ok, so i can replace convertion in seconds (return float(( ...)) with "result.seconds". Tomorrow i will fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The subtraction of two different `datetime` already returns a delta. [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

The params `origin` and `datetime` have to be a `datetime` object. Either make both params to a `datetime` object or the object that is `datetime.time` to an current **date**time` object.

For converting your `time` to `datetime`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474670/pythonic-way-to-combine-datetime-date-and-datetime-time-objects) may help or you adjust the fields manually.

```py
import datetime

t = datetime.time(1, 2, 3)
print('t :', t)

d = datetime.date.today()
print('d :', d)

dt = datetime.datetime.combine(d, t)
print('dt:', dt)
```

#### output

```py
t : 01:02:03
d : 2013-02-21
dt: 2013-02-21 01:02:03
```