# check for overlap using datetime.combine

Tags: python

An example of a list showing date, start hour, finish hour and description:

```
A = [['24/02/2022', '11', '12', 'task1'],
     ['24/02/2022', '9', '10', 'task2'],
     ['24/02/2022', '14', '18', 'task1'],
     ['24/02/2022', '13', '14', 'task3']]
```

I would like to create a timespan for each list entry and check for time overlap between entries. List can contain a variable number of entries.

But I'm stuck on how to loop through `A` containing `n` number of lists to generate the datetime objects? I'm not sure how to extract the information and use something like `datetime.combine(date, time)` to create the objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One could put the data in a `pd.DataFrame`, then convert the `date` column to `pd.Timestamp`, and create `df.Timestamp` for `start` and `finish` by adding the respective hours and the date:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

A = [['24/02/2022', '11', '12', 'task1'],['24/02/2022', '9', '10', 'task2'],['24/02/2022', '14', '18', 'task1'],['24/02/2022', '13', '14', 'task3'] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['date', 'start', 'finish', 'description'])
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.start = df.apply(lambda x: x.date + pd.DateOffset(hours=float(x.start)), axis=1)
df.finish = df.apply(lambda x: x.date + pd.DateOffset(hours=float(x.finish)), axis=1)
df.drop(columns=['date'], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

prints:

```
            start              finish description
0 2022-02-24 11:00:00 2022-02-24 12:00:00       task1
1 2022-02-24 09:00:00 2022-02-24 10:00:00       task2
2 2022-02-24 14:00:00 2022-02-24 18:00:00       task1
3 2022-02-24 13:00:00 2022-02-24 14:00:00       task3
```

Then one could iterate over each pair (generated using `itertools` on the index) and check if either the start or finish timestamp of the latter (with index `j`) is in the range of the former (with index `i`), and, if so, add to a set `overlaps` the tuple `(i, j, overlap)`, as follows:

```
a, b = list(zip(*combinations(df.index, 2)))
overlaps = set()
iterable = zip(df.loc[a, :].iterrows(), df.loc[b, :].iterrows())
for (i, r1), (j, r2) in iterable:
    overlap = None
    if r1.start < r2.start < r1.finish:
        if r2.finish < r1.finish:
            overlap = r2.finish - r2.start
        else:
            overlap = r1.finish - r2.start
    elif r1.start < r2.finish < r1.finish:
        if r1.start < r2.start:
            overlap = r2.finish - r2.start
        else:
            overlap = r2.finish - r1.start
    if overlap is not None:
        overlaps.add((i, j, overlap))

for i, j, overlap in overlaps:
    print(f'Entries {i} and {j} overlap by {overlap}.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally, iterate through the list creating start and end datetime objects.
Here I simply print them but you can store them in another list, whatever, for later calculations.

```
import datetime

A = [['24/02/2022', '11', '12', 'task1'],['24/02/2022', '9', '10', 'task2'],['24/02/2022', '14', '18', 'task1'],['24/02/2022', '13', '14', 'task3'] ]

>>> A
[['24/02/2022', '11', '12', 'task1'], ['24/02/2022', '9', '10', 'task2'], ['24/02/2022', '14', '18', 'task1'], ['24/02/2022', '13', '14', 'task3']]
>>> for item in A:
...  start = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.strptime(item[0],'%d/%m/%Y'), datetime.time(int(item[1]), 0)) 
...  end = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.strptime(item[0],'%d/%m/%Y'), datetime.time(int(item[2]), 0)) 
...  print(start, end, item[3])
... 
2022-02-24 11:00:00 2022-02-24 12:00:00 task1
2022-02-24 09:00:00 2022-02-24 10:00:00 task2
2022-02-24 14:00:00 2022-02-24 18:00:00 task1
2022-02-24 13:00:00 2022-02-24 14:00:00 task3
```

See: [Pythonic way to combine datetime.date and datetime.time objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474670/pythonic-way-to-combine-datetime-date-and-datetime-time-objects)
for datetime.combine answer

Edit subject to your comment:

Why do the hard work when someone has already done that work for you?

There is a module called `DateTimeRange`
https://pypi.org/project/DateTimeRange/

Not tested exhaustively:

```
import datetime
from datetimerange import DateTimeRange

A = [
     ['24/02/2022', '11', '12', 'task0'], ['24/02/2022', '9', '10', 'task1'], ['24/02/2022', '14', '18', 'task2'],
     ['24/02/2022', '13', '14', 'task3'], ['24/02/2022', '13', '15', 'task4']
    ]

# periods will be [start, end, task_id, overlaps, overlaps_with]
periods = []

for item in A:
    start = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.strptime(item[0],'%d/%m/%Y'), datetime.time(int(item[1]), 0))
    end = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.strptime(item[0],'%d/%m/%Y'), datetime.time(int(item[2]), 0))
    periods.append([start, end, item[3], False, ''])

for period in periods:
    if period[3] == True: # test for already True overlap
        continue
    range = DateTimeRange(period[0], period[1])
    for test_loop in periods:
        if test_loop[2] == period[2]: # test for testing against self using task string
            continue
        test = DateTimeRange(test_loop[0], test_loop[1])
        if test.is_intersection(range):
            print (test_loop[2], "overlaps", period[2])
            period[3] = True
            period[4] += test_loop[2]+', '

for period in periods:
    print(period)
```

Results in:

```
task3 overlaps task2
task4 overlaps task2
task2 overlaps task3
task4 overlaps task3
task2 overlaps task4
task3 overlaps task4
[datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 24, 11, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 24, 12, 0), 'task0', False, '']
[datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 24, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 24, 10, 0), 'task1', False, '']
[datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 24, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 24, 18, 0), 'task2', True, 'task3, task4, ']
[datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 24, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 24, 14, 0), 'task3', True, 'task2, task4, ']
[datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 24, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 24, 15, 0), 'task4', True, 'task2, task3, ']
```

Comment: thankyou, with the first option, how could I Iterate through all possible combinations to check for any overlap? I have got what you have working, storing the start / end datetime objects in a list, but can't figure out how to check each pair against each other for overlap

Comment: @filipe See my latest edit

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
A = [['24/02/2022', '11', '12', 'task1'], ['24/02/2022', '9', '10', 'task2'],
     ['24/02/2022', '14', '18', 'task1'], ['24/02/2022', '13', '14', 'task3']]

A = [[datetime.combine(datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y'), dt.time(int(start, 0))),
      datetime.combine(datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y'), dt.time(int(end, 0))),
      task] for date, start, end, task in [*A]]
for item in A:
    print(*item)
```

Output:

```
2022-02-24 11:00:00 2022-02-24 12:00:00 task1
2022-02-24 09:00:00 2022-02-24 10:00:00 task2
2022-02-24 14:00:00 2022-02-24 18:00:00 task1
2022-02-24 13:00:00 2022-02-24 14:00:00 task3
```

Alternative Pandas method:

```
import pandas as pd

A = [['24/02/2022', '11', '12', 'task1'], ['24/02/2022', '9', '10', 'task2'],
     ['24/02/2022', '14', '18', 'task1'], ['24/02/2022', '13', '14', 'task3']]

df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['date', 'start', 'finish', 'description'])
df.start = pd.to_datetime(df.date + ' ' + df.start + ":00:00")
df.finish = pd.to_datetime(df.date + ' ' + df.finish + ":00:00")
df = df[['start', 'finish', 'description']]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                start              finish description
0 2022-02-24 11:00:00 2022-02-24 12:00:00       task1
1 2022-02-24 09:00:00 2022-02-24 10:00:00       task2
2 2022-02-24 14:00:00 2022-02-24 18:00:00       task1
3 2022-02-24 13:00:00 2022-02-24 14:00:00       task3
```

Comment: thankyou, with the first option, how could I Iterate through all possible combinations to check for any overlap?