# How do I combine a datetime and time fields?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two fields that I need to parse and combine together to form a full datetime field.

The first field is a date field but in the form of a datetime field already, like `2021-09-02 00:00:00.000000`. The second field is a timestamp field: `18:00:00`.

I want to combine these two fields to be like this: `2021-09-02 18:00:00.000000`.

I'm struggling to do this with the `datetime` package. I've tried string parsing and putting them together but can't get anything to work.

Comment: Are you looking for [datetime.combine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to combine datetime.date and datetime.time objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474670/pythonic-way-to-combine-datetime-date-and-datetime-time-objects)

Comment: Dear @simplycoding, can you share some code that you have already tried to code, it will be easy to help you from an example.