# python time subtraction

Tags: python, time

I want to get the time in Python.  With `time.ctime()`, there are lots of functions:

I tried:

```
def write_time():  
  NUMBER_OF_MIN=40 #my offset
  obj=time.gmtime()
  print  " D", obj.tm_mday, " M",obj.tm_mon,  "Y",obj.tm_year, 
  " time", obj.tm_hour+TIME_OFFSET,":",   obj.tm_min-NUMBER_OF_MIN, ":",obj.tm_sec
```

I want to subtract 40 minutes from the time.

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/python-easy-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-a-datetime-time

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Check out the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library, which provides much more flexibility for math using dates.

For example:

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now()
print datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)
print datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
print datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=400)
```

Prints:

```
el@dev ~ $ python test.py
2014-11-26 06:47:07.179411
2014-11-26 06:45:07.179538
2014-11-26 06:46:57.179581
2014-11-26 06:47:06.779614
```

Comment: Just in case it's not obvious, you can combine: `print datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours=24*3+16,minutes=23)`