# How to add and subtract times in python

Tags: python

I want to write a simple timesheet script. My input file looks like

```
9:00 17:00
10:45 12:35
11:00 15:00
```

I would like to read it in, compute the number of hours worked per day and then sum those hours up. When the day started before 12:00 and ended after 13:00 I would like to subtract half an hour too for lunch break.

My attempt so far is:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

gap = datetime.strptime('00:30','%H:%M')
hours = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    (start_time,end_time) = line.split()
    start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M')
    end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time, '%H:%M')
    #if start_time before 12:00 and end_time after 13:00 then subtract gap
    hours.append(end_time-start_time)       
print sum(hours)
```

I don't know how to get the if statement line to work and summing the hours doesn't seem to work either as you can't sum datetime.timedelta types.

---

Thanks to the link in the comments, replacing sum(hours) with reduce(operator.add, hours) works.

The remaining part is how to test if start_time is before 12:00 and end_time is after 13:00 and if so to reduce the timedelta by half an hour.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897246/python-time-subtraction

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096953/difference-between-two-time-intervals-in-python

Comment: @Fusseldieb I looked at your links thank you. It seems  reduce(operator.add, hours) is how you add the hours. How do you do the if statement and the gap subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

You are using incorrect code (and syntax) in your if statement.

```
if start_time < datetime.strptime('12:00', '%H:%M') and end_time > datetime.strptime('13:00', '%H:%M'):
    delta_hours = end_time.hour - start_time.hour)
    delta_minutes = end_time.minutes - start_time.minutes)
    # Do whatever your want with it now.
    # Substraction of the break is not implemented in this example, it depends on how you want to save it.
```

[Time delta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) might be worth looking into as well, it can use basic operations like

```
a = timedelta(...)
b = timedelta(...)
c = b - a - gap
```