# How to calculate the time and find the remaining hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Question How do I print out the remaining hours of overtime

Example: I have to be at work for 8 hours, and if my time goes over 8 hours as shown in OUTPUT then I just wanna have the 00:03:00 printed out.. 
Meaning that I have 3 min overtime that day.

```
from datetime import datetime

s1 = '07:15:00'
s2 = '16:18:00'
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'

tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)

print(tdelta)
```

OUTPUT

```
9:03:00
```

Comment: Take another look at your code.  You probably assigned `s3 = '08:00:00`  to reduce the difference of your `tdelta` but you never referenced it back.  How did you expect it to work? A hint: look into `datetime.timedelta`, it's used to add/subtract time difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python time subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897246/python-time-subtraction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract the length of the working day with a `timedelta` object...

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

s1 = '07:15:00'
s2 = '16:18:00'
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'

work_time = timedelta(hours=8)
lunch_time = timedelta(hours=1)

tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT) - work_time - lunch_time

print(tdelta)
```

Output:

```
0:03:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the length of the working day (and it would appear an hour to account for breaks) from `tdelta` to determine the excess.