# Time offset in python2.7

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

I'm trying to shift a time forward or backward depending on some integer value. So far, I've been just adding (or subtracting) that time shift from the hour then using mod 24 when I create the time

```
time_structure = datetime.time((hour + time_zone_shift)%24, minute, second)
```

This works for the most part (except with rolling back the date, i.e if the time given is 7:30 and then the time_zone_shift is -8). I was wondering if there is a more "pythonic" way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/python-easy-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-a-datetime-time

Comment: You might want to take a look at the pytz module: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't be doing this for time zone changes. There are ways to create timezone aware datetime objects.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question, you should use `datetime.timedelta` to offset a time:

```
time_structure = (datetime.datetime(0, 0, 0, hour, minute, second) + datetime.timedelta(hours=time_zone_shift)).time()
```

But as expressed in the comments, you should really use `pytz` for time zone math since it can be rather complicated.