# How to add time to date in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Want to add some time to existing date.

```
>>date='2013-11-16  22:00:00'
>>newdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()
>>print newdate
>>datetime.date(2013, 11, 16)
```

The last line is showing only date but not time. Why there is no time in last line ? How can i get date with added some time ?

Comment: `date()` converts a `datetime` object into a `date` object, which does not have a time. Why are you using it if you want the time? If you want to create a `datetime` object for a fixed time on the variable `date` object, `datetime.datetime.combine` is the preferred way to do that.

Comment: I think the followin link could help you guy:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/python-easy-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-a-datetime-time

Comment: Come to think of it, if you're starting from a string representing a datetime and want to change the time without changing the date, the `replace` method on the results of `datetime.datetime.strptime` might be the best way.