# Trying to display a variable as a time when printed

Tags: python-3.x

So i have a variable that needs to be displayed as a time of day, i.e 3:02, and then make calculations off of that variable, i.e add 7 to the first variable, wellington,and have it displayed as 3:09.
This is a simple question, and it doesn't need to go into the datetime
is there a way i can do it, without datetime?

```
def traintimes():
    crofton = wellington + 7
    ngaio = crofton + 2
    awarua = ngaio + 2
    simla = awarua + 2
    boxhill = simla + 1
    kandallah = boxhill + 2
    raroa = kandallah + 2
    johnsonville = raroa + 2
    print ("Wellington:",wellington,"Crofton Downs:",crofton,"Ngaio:",ngaio,"Awarua Street:",awarua,"Simla Crescent:",simla,"Box Hill:",boxhill,"Kandallah:",kandallah,"Raroa:",raroa,"Johnsonville:",johnsonville)
wellington = int("3:02")
traintimes ()
wellington = int("3:28")
traintimes()
wellington = int("3:40")
traintimes()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the standard way to add N seconds to datetime.time in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `datetime` module instead of working with ints. Use `timedelta` to make the calculations.

Example:

```
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

crofton = current_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=7)
```

Working with time can be very difficult without the correct library, I suggest taking the time to read the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) documentation.

Also, [this article](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) is pretty much required reading for all programers who work with time.

Comment: will this let me set it to a certain time of day?, like only 3:02, or 2:15?