# Adding seconds to time integer

Tags: c++

I have day's time in integer formats like 152947 for (15 hour,29 min and 47 seconds), if I add seconds to that then I have to get integer in same format. eg

152947 + 40 => 153027

I do not want to use any time function, I know can do things like

```
int add2time(int timenum, int secs_to_add){
  int hour = timenum/10000;
  int minute = (timenum/100)%100;
  int second = (timenum%100);
  secs = hour * 3600 + minute * 60 + second;
  secs += secs_to_add;
  return (secs / 3600)*10000+((secs % 3600)/60)*100 + (secs % 60);
}
```

but as usual, I am looking for some faster ways to directly manipulate integer.

The problem is similar to below
[What is the standard way to add N seconds to datetime.time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python)

Comment: You can just add directly to the integer. Is the integer in ms? Then just multiply secs_to_add by 60, then add.

Comment: if you add then second part of integer can exceed 60

Comment: you can take it apart after you add the seconds, and it will not exceed 60.