# Addition of two datetime.datetime.strptime().time() objects in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I want to add two time values t1 and t2 in format 'HH:MM:SS'.

```
t1 ='12:00:00'
t2='02:00:00'
```

`t1+t2` should be `14:00:00`

I tried `t1+t2`. But as `t1` & `t2` are im string format the output was concatenation `12:00:00 02:00:00`.

So I tried to convert in datetime.datetime.strptime().time() object like

```
t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('12:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('02:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
```

but gives error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

How can I get this to work?

[image]

Comment: Add the `datetime` objects, not the `time` objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the standard way to add N seconds to datetime.time in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, this is not a duplicate of the linked question since it already has a numbers of seconds to add.  The OP has two time stamps.

Answer (score 4):

You can not directly add two `time()` variables.  This is due to the fact that these time variables are not durations.  They are the time of day.  You can however turn a time variable into a duration by subtracting the zero element for this operation from the time variable (i.e. midnight).

**Test Code:**

```
import datetime as dt
t1 = dt.datetime.strptime('12:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
t2 = dt.datetime.strptime('02:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
time_zero = dt.datetime.strptime('00:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
print((t1 - time_zero + t2).time())
```

**Results:**

```
14:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you .It woks.@Stephen Rauch