# Converting time to am/pm using python

Tags: python, datetime, time

Im trying to convert my time to a 12 hour with AM/PM but i keep getting an error and have no idea why. The context is taking the last number of minutes and figuring out what time that ends up being. Here is my code, if anyone could help. It would be wonderful

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time

cumulative_myList = np.cumsum(myList)
time_in_minutes = cumulative_myList[-1]
time_in_seconds = time_in_minutes*60

print(time_in_seconds)

time = datetime.timedelta(0,time_in_seconds)
print(time)

last_bus_time = time.strptime(time, "%H:%M")
last_bus_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: `strptime()` is a method of `datetime`, not `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: And the first argument should be a string to parse, not a `timedelta`.

Comment: Im getting that and understand. But im not 100% sure in how to convert my minutes or seconds to AM/PM

Comment: Where is the time in your code? You're just adding a bunch of seconds, that isn't a time of day.

Comment: Im trying to use my results of how many minutes there are in order to figure out how many hours and minutes that a time is after midnight. Once you figure out how many hours and minutes there are. You need to figure out how to make that AM/PM so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datetime.timedelta` represents a duration, not a time of day. If you want to treat a duration as a time of day, you need to add it to a `datetime` object that contains the beginning of a day. So you can do:

```
time = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds = time_in_seconds)
print(time.strftime("%I:%M %p"))
```

The date 2000-01-01 is arbitrary, since we don't care what the date is, we just need one to get the time from it.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/mZYcPU)

See related: [What is the standard way to add N seconds to datetime.time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python)

Comment: This works except it just shows me 12am and not the amount of time from the datetime.timedelta function

Answer (score 0):

*strptime* is not a method of class *datetime.timedelta*.

You can check the available methods in the [python3 datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

You can also verify this from the repl:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> type(dt)
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> time = datetime.timedelta(0, 100)
>>> type(time)
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

If your time in seconds is from midnight, then you can simply construct a datetime object and add on your time:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt = dt.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
>>> time = datetime.timedelta(0,time_in_seconds)
>>> last_bus_time = dt + time
>>> last_bus_time.strftime("%I:%M%p")
```