# How to add an extra second to datetime.time object in python 3?

Tags: python

I am supposed to add an extra second to the field end_time which is of type . 
I am not able to add an extra second to the time, for example the time is 10:34:45 and I want to make the time as 10:34:46 then using timedelta function I am not able to add the second nor can I convert this object to datetime.datetime object.
The field is not a datetime.datetime field from the very start. The field is already a datetime.time object beforehand. So what is the best way to convert this datetime.time object to add the extra seconds.

```
print (end_time_n)
print (type(end_time_n))
```

Output:

```
12:17:04

<class 'datetime.time'>
```

Comment: What is the type of this field?

Comment: it is datetime.time field and it is defined as Timefield in django forms

Answer (score 2):

Using `datetime` module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
t = "10:34:45"
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M:%S")
print( (t + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)).strftime("%H:%M:%S") )
```

**Output:**

```
10:34:46
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,10,34,46)
b = a + datetime.timedelta(0,3) # days, seconds, then other fields.
print a.time()
print b.time()
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/100345/7678093

Answer (score 1):

Using datetime module and .timedelta function:

```
import datetime

x = datetime.timedelta(hours=10, minutes=20, seconds=30)
print (x) # returns 10:20:30

x = x + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
print (x) # returns 10:20:31
```