# How to solve "type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'" when creating a new date?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, datetime

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I'm trying to calculate a new datetime by adding a number of seconds to an existing datetime.  From this -- [What is the standard way to add N seconds to datetime.time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python), I thought i could do

```
new_date = article.created_on + datetime.timedelta(0, elapsed_time_in_seconds)
```

where "article.created_on" is a datetime and "elapsed_time_in_seconds" is an integer.  But the above is resulting in an

```
type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

error.  What am I missing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've imported the wrong thing; you've done `from datetime import datetime` so that `datetime` now refers to the class, not the containing module.

Either do:

```
import datetime
...article.created_on + datetime.timedelta(...)
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
...article.created_on + timedelta(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the correct import:

```
from datetime import timedelta

new_date = article.created_on + timedelta(0, elapsed_time_in_seconds)
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue, i solved it by replacing
`from datetime import datetime as my_datetime`
with
`import datetime as my_datetime`