# Why does the duration between Datetime and Timedelta come up 1h short?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, timedelta

I'm trying to automate documenting my worktimes and need a way to get the duration between the starting and ending time. During my research I came upon 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python)
question which seemed to provide a solution to my problem.

However, when trying to get the duration between "11:30" and "12:30" the datetime.time() method returns "00:00:00" and I have no idea why.

This is the code I'm using.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import strptime

start = strptime("11:30", "%H:%M")
stop = strptime("12:30", "%H:%M")

start_dt = datetime(100, 1, 1, start.tm_hour, start.tm_min)

duration = start_dt + timedelta(hours=stop.tm_hour,
                                minutes=stop.tm_min,
                                seconds=0)

print(duration.time())
```

This is my expected (desired) output:
`01:00:00`

This is the actual output I'm getting:
`00:00:00`

I was wondering whether it had something to do with the time.strptime() method I'm using to get hour and minute values so I tried this as well:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_dt = datetime(100, 1, 1, 11, 30)

duration = start_dt + timedelta(hours=12,
                                minutes=30,
                                seconds=0)

print(duration.time())
```

The output remains the same. Does anyone know why? I'm completely at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `11:30` + `12:30` is `00:00`, since there are two `:30`s you add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: you added up the two times whereas for a duration, you need to calculate the *difference*.

Because you added the two up. Indeed, your `start_dt` looks like: `1-1-100 11:30`, and you added `12:30` to that, so that means that:

```
start_dt   1-1-100  11:30
+                   12:30
-------------------------
           2-1-100  00:00
```

or midnight, the *next* day.

If you want to calculate the time difference, you can subtract the two, like:

```
start = datetime.strptime('11:30', '%H:%M')
stop = datetime.strptime('12:30', '%H:%M')
duration = stop - start  # minus (-), not plus (+)
```

this gives us then:

```
>>> duration
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
>>> str(duration)
'1:00:00'
```

so 3600 seconds, or one hour.

That being said, time is quite *ambiguous*, since it is timezone specific: dependong on where you are, and when (since some countries changed timezones), it can result in totally different results.

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I wanted it to. Seems pretty obvious now that I think about it.