# Issues incrementing start_time parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having issues incrementing the time in the start_time variable. I'm trying to have it so each loop-through it adds 5 seconds. I thought if I converted it to a timestamp and added 5000 to it, then converted back to iso that would work but it doesn't I get errors:

```
File "snaps.py", line 36, in <module>
    stamp += 5000
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

Code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import os
import dateutil.parser
import time

instrument = ('btc-usd')
exchange = ('cbse')  
start_time = '2021-01-26T00:00:00Z'
stamp = dateutil.parser.parse(start_time)
d_range = 'Jan-14-16' 
page_size = '1'

url = f'https://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v2/data/order_book_snapshots.v1/exchanges/{exchange}/spot/{instrument}/snapshots/depth'
params = { 'page_size': page_size, 'start_time': start_time }
KEY = 'xxx'
headers = {
    "X-Api-Key": KEY,
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
}

csv_file = f"Snapshot-{start_time}.csv"
snapshot = 0

while(snapshot <= 100):
    res = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    j_data = res.json()
    parse_data = j_data['data']  
   
    # create dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(parse_data), orient='columns')
    #df.insert(1, 'time', pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp.astype(int),unit='ms'))    
    snapshot += 1
    stamp += 5000
    start_time= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp).isoformat()
    #that means file already exists need to append
    if(csv_file in os.listdir()): 
        csv_string = df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8', header=False)
        with open(csv_file, 'a') as f:
            f.write(csv_string)
    #that means writing file for the first time        
    else: 
        csv_string = df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8')
        with open(csv_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(csv_string)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python

Comment: stamp = time.mktime(time.strptime('2021-7-10 17:53:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))