# How to add seconds to an already existing range of time with Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a range of dates and times in such a format, and I have to add seconds to this range.
**DateTime**
0        2021-07-20 23:59:00
1        2021-07-20 23:59:00
2        2021-07-20 23:59:00
3        2021-07-20 23:59:00
4        2021-07-20 23:59:00

357545   2021-07-12 00:00:00
357546   2021-07-12 00:00:00
357547   2021-07-12 00:00:00
357548   2021-07-12 00:00:00
357549   2021-07-12 00:00:00

how it says 23:59:00. I want this to change to the following.
DateTime
0        2021-07-20 23:59:00
1        2021-07-20 23:59:58
2        2021-07-20 23:59:56
3        2021-07-20 23:59:54
4        2021-07-20 23:59:52
5        2021-07-20 23:59:50
6        2021-07-20 23:59:48
7        2021-07-20 23:59:46
8        2021-07-20 23:59:44
9        2021-07-20 23:59:42

and so on.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend researching `datetime.timedelta`

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have code in your question it's hard to answer your question directly but I'll give it a shot.

You should be able to add seconds to a datetime string using strftime. Example from https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now() # current date and time
date_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")  # the %S will add seconds to the output
```

If you're trying to add seconds to an existing datetime object, you can use `timedelta` as described by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/100345/16338189

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,11,34,59)
b = a + datetime.timedelta(0,3) # adds 0 days and 3 seconds to 
print(a.time())
print(b.time())
```