# Adding constant time onto datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I have a datetime column where I am trying to add a constant number of seconds to the original time. The end goal is to create a rolling window function with a fixed window based on seconds. The first step is identical to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python/100345).

My question is why is my application of this solution to this question not working? How can I add a constant `timedelta` to the previous time in order to try and get the r

```
# ========== create dataset and try add 3 seconds to datetime column=================================================================== #

import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta, datetime


timestamp_list = ["2022-02-07 11:38:08.625",
                  "2022-02-07 11:38:09.676", 
                  "2022-02-07 11:38:10.084", 
                  "2022-02-07 11:38:10.10000",  
                  "2022-02-07 11:38:11.2320"]

value_list = [1.14338, 
                  1.14341, 
                  1.14340, 
                  1.1434334, 
                  1.1534334]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(zip(timestamp_list, value_list))
df.columns = ['timestamp','value']

# make date time object
df.timestamp = [datetime.strptime(time_i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") for time_i in df.timestamp]

# get the  time second value of datetime
df["timestamp_to_sec"] = df["timestamp"].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")

# add 3 seconds to the original timestep
temp = df.timestamp_to_sec + timedelta(seconds=3)
```

```
#output with error
0   -83211 days +23:06:15.727111680
1   -83211 days +23:06:16.727111680
2   -83211 days +23:06:17.727111680
3   -83211 days +23:06:17.727111680
4   -83211 days +23:06:18.727111680
Name: timestamp_to_sec, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for datetimes, then remove microseconds by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) and add 3 seconds:

```
# make date time object
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)

# get the  time second value of datetime
df["timestamp"] = df["timestamp"].dt.floor('s') + pd.Timedelta(seconds=3)
   
print (df)
            timestamp     value
0 2022-02-07 11:38:11  1.143380
1 2022-02-07 11:38:12  1.143410
2 2022-02-07 11:38:13  1.143400
3 2022-02-07 11:38:13  1.143433
4 2022-02-07 11:38:14  1.153433
```