# How to sum time HH:MM:SS with seconds on shell?

Tags: python, shell, date, math, time

How can I sum a time in HH:MM:SS with another one time in second in shell or python? For example, suppose that the time is 07:12:54 and I need to add 2000.234 seconds, how can I calculate the output time in HH:MM:SS after the sum? And how will be if I wanna decrease the seconds of the HH:MM:SS time?

thanks,

Comment: For Python see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python

Comment: What have you tried? Please show it and explain how its output differs from what you expected.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are doing this in [tag:python] or [tag:shell]?

Comment: I am processing a set of signals with more than 100 inside a for loop on shell. I have two variables: one presenting travel time in seconds (t_wave_travel_time_sec=`echo "scale=2; $epic_dist / 1.5" | bc`) and another one with the origin time (origin_time=`awk ' NR==n {print $3}' n=$n $filename `) in hh:mm:ss. I need to calculate the "t_wave_arrival_time" that will be the origin time + t_wave_travel_time_sec.

Comment: But I am stuck and do not know how to do because some functions like datetime on python look like to need the information separate hh mm ss, however, they are only separated by the ':' on my case (ex: 07:17:46, 07:26:35, 08:24:15....).

Comment: I asked on python because if someone now a way on python I can create a code on python and include it inside of the shell, similar I have done to calculate distance: epic_dist=`python3 distance.py $slat $slon $epiclat $epiclon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way should be using datetime with timedelta:

```
import datetime
time = datetime.datetime.strptime("07:12:54", "%H:%M:%S") # suppose that the time is 07:12:54
print(time.strftime ("%H:%M:%S"))
delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=2000.234) # I need to add 2000.234 seconds
print(delta)
new_time = time + delta # calculate the output time in HH:MM:SS
print(new_time.strftime ("%H:%M:%S"))
new_time2 = time - delta # decrease the seconds of the HH:MM:SS time
print(new_time2.strftime ("%H:%M:%S"))
```

resulting in the output:

```
07:12:54
0:33:20.234000
07:46:14
06:39:33
```

Comment: Ok. I created the code and tried to execute code, including some time examples as input:  python3.9 arrival_time.py 12:22:22 2304.34

Comment: import datetime
import sys

time = datetime.datetime.strptime("float(sys.argv[1])", "%H:%M:%S") # suppose that the time is 07:12:54
print(time.strftime ("%H:%M:%S"))
delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=float(sys.argv[2])) # I need to add 2000.234 seconds
print(delta)
new_time = time + delta # calculate the output time in HH:MM:SS
print(new_time.strftime ("%H:%M:%S"))
new_time2 = time - delta # decrease the seconds of the HH:MM:SS time
print(new_time2.strftime ("%H:%M:%S"))

Comment: However, it did not work.

Comment: time = datetime.datetime.strptime("float(sys.argv[1])", "%H:%M:%S") # suppose that the time is 07:12:54
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
   raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'float(sys.argv[1])' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Comment: `"float(sys.argv[1])"` is a literal string. You likely want `sys.argv[1]`: no double quotes, and no conversion to float, since it's a string that you're going to parse.